# Proving power of 2 is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been working through a math tutorial and was asked the above question. I have been reading up on bijective, surjective and injective functions but am finding it quite difficult to understand. Could someone talk me through the steps required to solve this? Thank you in advance.

edited:
"Show that the set of numbers which are powers of 2 is a countably infinite set"

Comment: What power exactly? $2^{\aleph_0} $?

Comment: Could you state the full question here?

Comment: sorry, i have edited post.

Answer (score 3):

$n\mapsto 2^n$ is a quite obvious bijection of $\Bbb N$ with the set of powers of $2$.

Comment: It's obvious enough that the existence of this question means it may be worth explaining for OP why it is so.

Comment: could you elaborate on this? I'm not really looking for the answer, more the steps on how to solve it. I have read up quite a bit on function behavior and find myself at a loss

Answer (score 2):

The question as written is a bit ambiguous. For example, you can consider 3 as a power of 2, in that $2^{\log_2 3}=3$.

I would guess that from the problem statement as written, you want to do either integral powers of 2, or integral and their reciprocals, i.e. $\{1,2,4, \cdots \}$ or $\{\cdots \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, 1,2,4, \cdots \}$ - Both sets are countably infinite.

In order to prove something is infinite, you need to show that it's not finite - I think that's clear. In order to show that it's countable, you need to define a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to your set. As Hagen von Eitzen wrote above, $n\mapsto 2^n$ suffices for the first possibility. Let's let $R=\{\cdots \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, 1,2,4, \cdots \}$ and consider $n\rightarrow R.$ In order to make this work, we first need to rearrange R as follows, by proving set equality:  $$\{\cdots \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, 1,2,4, \cdots \} = \{ 1,\frac{1}{2},2,\frac{1}{4},4, \cdots \}.$$ I'll leave that part to you.

I'm going to be a little free with the notation in order to explain this best.

In order to figure out how to map $n$ to $R$, we can think in terms of the bijection $R \mapsto \log_2 R$.
$$\log_2 R=\{0,-1,1,-2,2\cdots\}.$$ We can then envisage a map from $\mathbb{N}$ to this set as $n \mapsto \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor (-1)^{n-1}$. We can then define the map from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow R$ as:
$$ n\mapsto 2^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor (-1)^{n-1}}.$$

Now that you have defined the map, you now need to prove that it's a surjection. It's also injective, which is not strictly required by the definition, but it's cleaner.